# Min-height auto ignored in iOS mobile

Tags: css, media-queries

I have some list items set to `min-height: 12em` - for desktop

When sizing down for tablet / mobile screens I want to reset this to: `min-height: auto`

However iPad / iPhone is ignoring this and maintains the 12em

I've also set `height: auto`

Comment: HOW are you changing this property for the iOS devices? Is it working on Android? Without more information this is just a guessing game.

Comment: Are you working in titanium iphone development?

Comment: Post your media queries css.

Comment: hi - Sorry I don't have Android to test on - it works on the Responsinator site but not on the actual device - css is:

    /* Desktop */
    .listings.default li {min-height: 12em;}

    /* Between Desktop and Tablet */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 768px) { 
    .listings.default li {min-height: auto; height: auto}
    }

Comment: Have you tried min-height: 0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
/* Desktop */
.listings.default li {
    min-height: 12em;
} 

/* Between Desktop and Tablet */ 
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 768px) { 
    .listings.default li {
        display: list-item;
        min-height: inherit;
    }
}
```

So use `inherit` instead of `auto`

I tested this on my iPhone but with another media query..
Check [this post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) to see some of the media queries for standard devices..

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 768px) { 
    min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

Is the best way, I think.